# BBB unable to ping 8.8.8.8

Tags: beagleboneblack

I am trying to follow Derek Molloy's tutorial here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzRVVtGNfj8

I was able to ping my laptop from the BBB through putty after editing my firewall settings.  Now, when I try to ping 8.8.8.8 nothing happens.  I believe I have followed the tutorial correctly.  Here is my output:

```
root@beaglebone:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3999ms
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My limited knowledge of the BeagleBone is leading me to believe the problem is that I am trying to access the internet through gateway 192.168.7.1 instead of my wireless router.  However, when I use ipconfig in Windows the to find the IP address for the wireless router and use that as the gw, I get an error from my BeagleBone saying it is unavailable.

Comment: Hello, anybody out there?  I am getting nowhere with this.  Just looking for some help trouble shooting.

Answer (score 0):

Do you using any USB adapters for Wi Fi?
When i had the same problem I just disconnect that USB Wi Fi adapter and this starting to works.

Another thing, check if you have IP address configured to 192.168.7.2 on yours Ethernet over USB network connection to BBB.